# Selenium can't click the button of a webpage python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am trying to click a vote button on a webpage. I can navigate the page with my python code and click on a radio button. The vote button is not declared as a "button" or "input" element in the HTML code. I am really unsure of how to have Selenium navigate to it and click on it. The button itself does not link to a web address. I have tried tabbing to it and then hitting enter but it tabs over the button itself. I can provide further HTML and any other supplementary information. A picture of the HTML is below!

[HTML Code of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqdQM.png)

Comment: The "a" in the HTML as far as I have read about is an "anchor element". I do not know HTML so I am having a hard time finding a work around for the way this button operates.

Comment: Maybe try finding the element by xpath, and see whether that works?

Comment: I have tried that route but even by using the xpath I can’t click on the element. It’s as if it isn’t recognized as a clickable item.

Comment: Could you add a link to the webpage if possible?

Comment: https://threerivers.okvype.com/2020/02/24/vote-now-okmulgee-area-preseason-baseball-poll-presented-by-muscogee-creek-nation-poll-ends-3-2/

Comment: Hello, would it be possible to add your original code to the post so that we know what you had done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options = driver_options)
driver.get("https://threerivers.okvype.com/2020/02/24/vote-now-okmulgee-area-preseason-baseball-poll-presented-by-muscogee-creek-nation-poll-ends-3-2/")
buttonpath = '//*[@id="pd-vote-button10509753"]'
dotpath = '//*[@id="PDI_answer48619888"]'
dot = driver.find_element_by_xpath(dotpath)
vote = driver.find_element_by_xpath(buttonpath)
dot.click()
vote.click()
```

It worked for me, by selecting the right elements to click. Sometimes theres a wrapping element around the button that has to receive the click instead of the target element, in order to trigger a response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the element using the class selectors?

I would get the SelenideElement by class and then calling the click method: $('.pds-vote-button')

Comment: I have tried that method using the class selectors. It didn't work. My implementation may have been incorrect.